# How to display image in sidebar-wrapper css class

Tags: html, css

I want to display image in #sidebar-wrapper class, i am using following code:

CSS:

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
  background-image:url('/images/nav.jpg');
  margin-left: -250px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="MainMenu">
            <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/home.png">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
               <ul class="sidebar-brand">
                 <li><a href="navigation.html">sub menu 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">sub menu 2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">sub menu 3</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">sub menu 4</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">sub menu 5</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">sub menu 6</a></li>
               </ul>                  
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Image is not being displayed. Any help or reference will be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Can you show us your HTML or create a http://jsfiddle.net demo? `position: fixed` fixes the position relative to the screen - if you scroll the page, the element will stay in the same position on the screen. I imagine this is probably what is causing the problem.

Comment: Can u showcase ur code

Comment: your code is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/afhx9du7/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this, it should work fine:

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
  background:url(/images/nav.jpg) no-repeat center; //  an maybe the quotes are not necessary. Check if the path is correct!
  background-size: cover; //  change this to 'contain' if you want to test different modes
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  margin-left: -250px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: Sorry! it's not working. When i inspect the element "background-image" property is not visible.

Comment: @MianOmerZia Sorry, I made a little mistake, now should work fine, check it :)

Comment: @MianOmerZia Glad to help ^^